# How to convert byte values in a dataframe to regular integers in python

Tags: python, dataframe, parentheses

How I imported the dataset into python after downloading it from the website (UCI machine learning)

Here is the link to the dataset: https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/00327/

```
From scipy.io import arff
Import pandas as pd
```

```
Data = arff.loadarff('Training Dataset.arff')
Data = pd.DataFrame(Data[0])
```

The value in my data set look like this: `b'-1'`, `b'1'` and `b'0'`

Please how do I change the values from the above to just regular integers like: `1`, `-1` and `0`

Update

After applying the code below, my out is not in a dataframe format, which is not what I want.
I would like the dataframe format to be the output.

```
for col in df:
    df = df[col].astype(str).str.decode("utf-8")
```

```
-1
1
-1
0
-1
1
```

Comment: What do you mean by data set? A `set` object, a list, or...? It would be helpful to show your actual code.

Comment: b'1' is byte string. There is no letter here. You have to decode it in order to get string. Or just apply `int` to convert it into integer.

Comment: Corrected it, it's apostrophes ( ' ) and the (b) attached to the values.

Comment: How did you obtain the values? A correct solution depends on properly understanding the original source.

Comment: Here is a link to the dataset (Training_Dataset.arff) on UCI machine learning site: https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/00327/

Answer (score 1):

Here is how:

```
for col in df:
    df = df[col].astype(str).str.decode("utf-8")
```

---

---

#### For the updated question:

```
lst = [b'-1', b'1', b'0' ]
lst = [int(s.decode()) for s in l]
print(lst)
```

Output:

```
[-1, 1, 0]
```

Comment: It is a dataframe

Comment: @Osemu Well then, use my first answer.

Comment: I get this error message: Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_  dtype in pandas

Comment: NameError: name 'l' is not defined

Comment: I have tried both, non has worked. Please take a look at my question again, I have updated it to show how I loaded the dataset and from the source